# Check if 2 input match an array element in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Basically, I have a very big 2D array that contains thousands of array represent data of zip code and city in a form like this `['14167', 'Berlin']`.
What I need to do is checking the input of zip code and city from a form to see if it match the data from the array and:

1. If the city cannot be found in the array, then show an error alert.
2. If the city is found but the zip code does not match, show a window that said "did you mean this?" and insert the right zip code in the form automatically.
3. If the city and zip code match, show a window that says it matches, and then the form should be reset.

What i have written so far:

```
function zipCheck(arr,k){
    var check=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var index = arr[i].indexOf(k);
        if (index > -1) {
            var val = index - 1;
            check.push(arr[i][val]);
            return check;
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried to do here is that I tried to use indexOf to check the position of the city input and use that position to push the matching zip codes to a different array. Then I will try to check the zip code input value to see if it match any element of the pushed array. The problem with my code is that I can only push the first zip code value to the check array while there might still be zip codes that match that city. Example: `['14131','Berlin'],['14163','Berlin'],['14165','Berlin']`.
Can someone help me fix my code or is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: The function needs to take both the city and zip code as inputs, so it can check if they match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` to find all the elements for the city. Then use `some()` to test if any of them have the entered zip code.

```js
function zipCheck(arr, city, zip) {
  let items = arr.filter(el => el[1] == city);
  if (!items) {
    alert(`City ${city} not found`);
  } else if (!items.some(el => el[0] == zip)) {
    alert(`Zip ${zip} is not found for ${city}`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both the city and zipcode to the function

Filtering through the 2D array to check for all items with a city, then map out the zipcodes.

First, I check if the check variable has any elements in it which mean there are cities, then i check if the passed zip code exists. If it doesn't it offers the first element in our check variable. Else it alerts match

```js
function zipCheck(arr, city, zip) {
  const check = arr.filter(item => item[1] == city).map(item => item[0]);
  
  if (!check.length) console.log(`City ${city} does not exist`);
  else if (check.findIndex(item => item == zip) > -1) console.log(`Couldn't find zipcode ${zip} did you mean ${check[0]}`)
  else console.log(`Matched ${city}, ${zip}`);
}

const data = [['14131','Berlin'],['14163','Berlin'],['14165','Berlin']];

zipCheck(data, 'Berlin');
zipCheck(data, 'Home');
```